# Laravel 4 IP based users?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm not sure what the term for this is, but I want everyone who visits the site to have their IP entered in the users table so I can transparently keep track of them. It'd be nice if they could sign up normally if they want at some point too.

Is there a proper way to do this in Laravel 4?

Edit: I want users to only be an IP, no username or password. When someone visits, if that IP exists, return that user object, if not, insert a new user based on their IP.

Comment: IP addresses get recycled all the time from one user to another.  As long as you understand that IP ≠ user, and you're not actually storing personal info in the user record, maybe this will be okay.  But please don't think you're actually authenticating the *real user* based on IP alone.  Simply not possible.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing int is to put something like this on a file like your app/start/global.php:

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    Auth::user()->ip_address = Request::getClientIp();
    Auth::user()->save();
}
```

And, of course, you'll also need the ip_address column to be added to your users table;

Comment: You might also want to consider having a pivot table. A single user may visit your site from multiple devices and/or locations!